# Forward function signature in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, type-hinting, python-typing

Say I have a function in `src/f1.py` with the following signature:

```py
def my_func(a1: int, a2: bool) -> float:
    ...
```

In a separate file `src/f2.py` I create a dictionary:

```py
from src.f1 import my_func

my_dict = {
    "func": my_func
}
```

In my final file `src/test1.py` I call the function:

```py
from src.f2 import my_dict

print(my_dict["func"](1, True))
```

I'm getting IDE auto-suggestions for `my_func` in `src/f2.py`, but not in `src/test1.py`. I have tried using [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable), but it doesn't create the same signature and it loses the function documentation. Is there any way I can get these in `src/test1.py` without changing the structure of my code?
I don't want to change the files in which my functions, dictionaries, or tests are declared.

I use VSCode version `1.73.1` and Python version `3.8.13`. I cannot change my Python version.

I tried creating different types of `Callable` objects, but had problems getting the desired results.

1. They seem to have no docstring support
2. Some types are optional. I couldn't get that to work.
3. They do not work with variable names, only data types. I want the variable names (argument names to the function) to be there in the IDE suggestion.

---

### What am I trying to do really?

I am trying to implement a mechanism where a user can set the configurations for a library in a single file. That single file is where all the dictionaries are stored (and it imports all essential functions).

This "configuration dictionary" is called in the main python file (or wherever needed). I have functions in a set of files for accomplishing a specific set of tasks.
Say functions `fa1` and `fa2` for task `A`; `fb1`, `fb2`, and `fb3` for task `B`; and `fc1` for task C. I want configurations (choices) for task A, followed by B, then C. So I do

```py
work_ABC = {"A": fa1, "B": fb2, "C": fc1};
```

Now, I have a function like

```py
wd = work_ABC
def do_work_abc(i, do_B=True):
    res_a = wd["A"](i)
    res_b = res_a
    if do_B:
        res_b = wd["B"](res_a)
    res_c = wd["C"](res_b)
    return res_c
```

If you have a more efficient way how I can implement the same thing, I'd love to hear it.

I want IntelliSense to give me the function signature of the function set for the dictionary.

Comment: 1) _"I don’t want to change the files in which my functions, dictionaries, or tests are declared."_ Then what **do** you want to change? 2) Please provide some more real-world context. What purpose does `my_dict` serve and why can't you import `my_func` from `f1` to call it directly?

Comment: 1. I meant that I do not want to move all functions into a single file (which would solve the problem but would make my scripts insanely large).

Comment: 2. In a module, I have many functions in `f1.py` (equivalent), and I want the dictionary to act as a look-up table. The user gives the dictionary key as input, and the function to the corresponding key has to be called. It works, I want IntelliSense also to give suggestions (it does if everything is in the same file for some reason).

Comment: I understood your code, but I asked for a real-world use case and why you would use a dictionary to look up functions instead of just importing it into your current namespace. Is this just an academic exercise born out of curiosity or does this serve any practical purpose?

Comment: Your question also has little to do with types. You already mentioned yourself that you _can_ annotate the types properly with `typing.Callable`. You are asking how to tell IntelliSense about the docstring and parameter names. This has nothing to do with type hints. The type of `f(x: str) -> int` is exactly the same as `g(y: str) -> int`. I think you confuse the terms _"type hint"_ and _"auto-suggestion"_.

Comment: I am trying to implement a mechanism where a user can set the configurations for a library in a single file. That single file is where all the dictionaries are stored (and it imports all essential functions). I have edited the question with more clarity. However, I am thankful for your answer, as I think it answers the question well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type annotation construct in Python that covers docstrings or parameter names of functions. There isn't even one for positional-only or keyword-only parameters (which would be actually meaningful in a type sense).

As I already mentioned in my comment, docstrings and names are not type-related. Ultimately, this is an IDE issue. PyCharm for example has no problem inferring those details with the setup you provided. I get the auto-suggestion for `my_dict["func"]` with the parameter names because PyCharm is smart/heavy enough to track it to the source. But it has its limits. If I change the code in `f2` to this:

```py
from src.f1 import my_func

_other_dict = {
    "func": my_func
}
my_dict = {}
my_dict.update(_other_dict)
```

Then the suggestion engine is lost.

The reason is simply the discrepancy between runtime and static analysis. At some point it becomes silly/unreasonable to expect a static analysis tool to essentially run the code for you. This is why I always say:

> Static type checkers don't execute your code, they just read it.

Even the fact that PyCharm "knows" the signature of `my_func` with your setup entails it running some non-trivial code in the background to back-track from the dictionary key to the dictionary to the actual function definition.

So in short: It appears you are out of luck with VSCode. And parameter names and docstrings are not part of the type system.

Comment: > `Static type checkers don't execute your code, they just read it.`


It makes sense that I won't get the function signature if they're in different files (it'll require execution). And you're right that Python (as a language) supports only type hints through Typing, so there's not much I can do about it.